# Swagger 2.0 not showing response class schema

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I updated my solution to `Swagger 2.0` via the `Swashbuckle` nuget pkg. Since updating, Swagger API no longer shows documentation for the response class. I still have my routes in my controller decorated with the `[ResponseType(typeof(MyObject))]` which previously, would fill the response class sections under swagger, but this doesn't seem to get picked up anymore. Am I missing something in the update?

**EDIT:**

This is what I no longer see after updating

[image]

Comment: Do you not see the response class schema in swagger-ui or in the Swagger documentation produced from Swashbuckle?

Comment: That's the UI, but that doesn't help isolating the problem. You need to check the generated Swagger document and see if it's documented there. The issue you describe could be either at what Swashbuckle produces or in Swagger-UI itself.

Comment: How do I access/find the generated Swagger document?

Comment: I'm not sure how Swashbuckle exposes it, but you can either look at the index.html and see the `url` parameter for the SwaggerUi object, or open the browser's console and see which url it ends up reading.

Answer (score 3):

Are you specifying response codes? If so be sure to include `<response code="200">OK</response>` to get the response class to show up.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this issue by replacing the `[ResponseType(typeof(MyObject))]` attribute with the following:

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(MyObject), 200)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify the ResponseType

```
**[ResponseType(typeof(YourOuputModel))]**
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string ListingId)
```

Comment: Worked for me! (just be sure to remove the **)

Comment: The question states that this attribute is present - and that it's not appearing in the swagger UI

Answer (score 1):

You can add just SwaggerResponse attribute :

```
[SwaggerResponse(200, "OK", typeof(ResponseEntity))]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string Id, string model)
```